# Get the index of an element given a constant class and unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery, uuid

How can one get the index of an element using its ID in a situation like this:

```
<div class="example" id="f126759614"></div>
<div class="example" id="ac0813e658"></div>
<div class="example" id="9b4f47250e"></div>
<div class="example" id="00dc780b73"></div>
<div class="example" id="ca6441a472"></div>
<div class="example" id="8c909d1e96"></div>
```

For example, if I wanted to get the index of `.example #f126759614`, it would be "0", and if `.example #8c909d1e96` was entered, it would return "5".

(The IDs are actually UUIDs; I just shortened them for the sake of the example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.index()` method](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to return the index of the element.

The index is zero-based, therefore the first element would have an index of `0`:

```
$('#f126759614').index(); // 0
$('#9b4f47250e').index(); // 2
```

Example:

```js
$('.example').text(function() {
  return $(this).index();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="example" id="f126759614"></div>
  <div class="example" id="ac0813e658"></div>
  <div class="example" id="9b4f47250e"></div>
  <div class="example" id="00dc780b73"></div>
  <div class="example" id="ca6441a472"></div>
  <div class="example" id="8c909d1e96"></div>
</div>
```

---

To handle cases where there are multiple sibling elements, and you only want to retrieve the index relative to specific elements, you can pass a selector:

```
$('.example').index($('#f126759614')); // 0
$('.example').index($('#9b4f47250e')); // 2
```

For instance:

```js
$('.example').text(function() {
  return $('.example[id]').index(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="example" id="f126759614"></div>
  <div>Skip this</div>
  <div class="example" id="ac0813e658"></div>
  <div class="example" id="9b4f47250e"></div>
  <div class="example" id="00dc780b73"></div>
  <div>Skip this</div>
  <div class="example" id="ca6441a472"></div>
  <div class="example" id="8c909d1e96"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you want to get an Index based on ID, you can do like this :

```
// would return 4
alert( $( '.example' ).index( $( '#ca6441a472' ) ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it: `$('#id').index('.class');`, for example:

```
$('#00dc780b73').index('.example');
```

```js
console.log( $('#00dc780b73').index('.example') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" id="f126759614"></div>
<div class="example" id="ac0813e658"></div>
<div class="example" id="9b4f47250e"></div>
<div class="example" id="00dc780b73"></div>
<div class="example" id="ca6441a472"></div>
<div class="example" id="8c909d1e96"></div>
```